# Copy file into new directory (PHP)

Tags: php, file-put-contents

I asked a similar question previously, but didn't know how to quite ask before. Below I created a new directory based on the username I grabbed from a signup form. I just need the inclusion of the template file copied over to the new directory that was just made. The outcome I'm getting is an inclusion of the file in the directory that's up one level. The new directory is created with the username but doesn't contain the template file in its directory. I spent hours on this so I wouldn't have to bother you guys again. **What am I doing wrong?**

```
 $folder = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; // adds the forward slash
   $name = $user->username;   // included from a login script I purchased 
   $thisdir = "../associate"; // desired directory
   $folderPath = $thisdir . $folder . $name;
   $file = copy('../associate/joshua/career.php', $folderPath.'.php'); // copy this file into new directory
        if(!file_exists($folderPath)){
            mkdir($folderPath);
            chmod($folderPath,0777);
        }

     file_put_contents(realpath($folderPath) .'/'. $folderPath, $file);

    });
```

Comment: You should read your code carefully because you are doing things that just can't work.

Comment: did you delete the previous, lower value question or open two, similar questions?

Comment: You're trying to write the file twice, first time you try to copy it and then you try to put the contents but you pass a bool as a file content. You really need to read the manual for the functions you're using.

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* - [Find out for yourself, see if anything comes of this. This being a hyperlink; **click it.**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: I have a debugging feature on. Doesn't mean I understand it all. I'm only three days into PHP. Sorry about that, Fred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to copy career.php template from /associates/ folder to /associates/username/ folder

```
   $rootfolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $name = $user->username;  
   $thisdir = "/associate/";
   $folderPath = $rootfolder.$thisdir.$name."/"; // desired directory

if(!is_dir($folderPath)){
        mkdir($folderPath, 0777, true);
    }
$currentfile = $rootfolder.$thisdir.'joshua/career.php';
    $destination = $folderPath.'career.php';
  copy($currentfile, $destination); // copy this file into new directory
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick, Andy. It did create the directory, but it doesn't contain a file.

Comment: You have to make sure the the file 'carre.php' you are copying exists at /associate/ folder

Comment: Just added a small edit. I added the correct folder path. "joshua/associate" and also move $destination to the correct location. You had $folderPath in the copy function instead of the $destination variable you created. Thank you a ton, Andy. Your work was a big help and explanation.

Comment: You are welcome @JoshuaAdams I have updated the typos you noted.